# Block drush rsync command when specific alias is set as destination

Tags: drush

I already have `policy.drush.inc` inside my Drupal drush directory at `sites/all/drush`.  Also, I have a policy set to prevent `sql-sync` if the `@staging` alias is set.  Thus,

```
drush sql-sync @dev @staging
```

will fail with the output `Per sites/all/policy.drush.inc, you may never overwrite the staging database.`

This was done with

```
function drush_policy_sql_sync_validate($source = NULL, $destination = NULL) { 
  if ($destination == '@staging') {
    return drush_set_error('POLICY_DENY', dt('Per sites/all/policy.drush.inc, you may never overwrite the staging database.'));
  }
}
```

This function is working, and I want to do the same for the rsync command, so basically duplicated the function and replaced `sql_sync` with `core_rsync` as in

```
function drush_policy_core_rsync_validate($source = NULL, $destination = NULL){
  if ($destination == "@staging") {
    return drush_set_error("POLICY_DENY", dt("Per sites/all/policy.drush.inc, you may not sync external files to staging"));
  }
}
```

However, I still get the 'You will destroy data from $remote and replace with data from $local` warning when executing

```
drush rsync @dev:%files @staging:%files
```

How can I block drush rsync from executing and why does this function work for `sql-sync` but not `core-rsync'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of rsync, `$destination` is equal to `@staging:%files`, which is different than `@staging`.  `drush_sitealias_evaluate_path` is not called until after the validate function, and calling it twice would be slow.  You could test to see if `$destination` is `@staging` OR if it begins with `@staging:`.  That should work well enough for your purposes.

If you wanted your policy to depend on values set in your @staging alias, then it would be best to make Drush call `drush_sitealias_evaluate_path` before the validate function.  That would be a feature request, and should be done by posting an issue (or better yet, a PR) on the Drush project on GitHub.